# How to stack elements along the z axis without using absolute positioning?

Tags: css

Let's say that I want to have layout that doesn't scroll (meaning width=100, height=100) with one container and 
two child elements. Now, when you don't apply any of the positioning context, all the elements follow natural flow of the document which means they stack below each other. How do I achieve positioning along the z-axis (stack them in front of each other) without using absolute positioning?

To be precise, here is fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Rokke/wb10ozme/7/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child-01">Child-01</div>
  <div class="child-02">Child-02</div>
</div>


html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.child-01 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: red;
}
.child-02 {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

What I want to achieve: child-01 centered horizontally on the page along the bottom edge of the screen, child-02 centered horizontally as well but in front of child-01. I accomplished this by using absolute positioning but then when you open up the developer tools it moves (because of the bottom: 0 property). If I was to use position relative I would have to use negative margin to bring them in front of each other. Does anyone have some idea how this can be achieved in a much better way?

Comment: FYI you can "detach" developer tools from the window (or move it to the right hand side) under the 3 vertical dots and changing the "Dock side" to one of the other options.

Comment: [This link](http://jsfiddle.net/3WDf7/) might  help you.

Comment: Could you explain why you do not want to use absolute positioning? Could you provide an image of what you're hoping to achieve? have you played with [`transform:translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

Comment: I know how to detach dev tools, but can you imagine what will happen when you open the keyboard on mobile device which btw can not be detached? :D Anyway, regarding transform I could use that but that's not the original purpose of this property. Truth to be told, I hate CSS hacks. I like using things while keeping in mind their original purpose.  I tried in my project applying negative margins and relative positioning and it's working now as it should. But I always wonder if I'm doing things the right way.

Comment: P.S. I will update my fiddle so you can see clearly what was my idea.

Comment: Sorry, your question is confusing. You say the fiddle shows what you want, but the result of the fiddle has nothing to do with the question text. Unless there's something I'm missing, a fiddle that does show what you want would look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/wb10ozme/14/

Comment: Anyway, why do you want to avoid `position:absolute`? if you want to stick something to the bottom of something else, you can hardly get around `position:absolute; bottom:0`. That's what it there for!

Comment: Here's the fiddle and initial idea:   http://jsfiddle.net/Rokke/3WDf7/625/

Comment: @MrLister What you did is perfect solution but why did you have to use transform?